# Partially processing a file with the preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

We have inherited a very convolved project (500kloc) with a **lot** of preprocessor conditional logic, most of which is no longer relevant, and I want to clean it up.

Can I use the preprocessor¹ to expand only *some* of the conditional logic, and leave all other preprocessor macros, defines, and includes alone in the output?

¹ Here, by "the preprocessor", I really mean "any tool", either a standard C preprocessor, something I can install, or even a hacked-together Perl or Python script.

---

For instance, suppose we have this set of code:

```
#include <foo>
#define baz
#define bar(a) do{(a)+1} \
               while(0)
#ifdef X
  #if Y > 20
    #if Z > 5
      so_far_so_good = true;
    #endif
    #ifdef baz
    something();
    #endif
  #else
    otherthing();
  #endif
#else
  #if Z > 10
    wow().this.is.bad;
  #endif
#endif
```

The tool I want (and might need to write if it doesn't exist) would be a version of CPP that accepts not only the list of definitions for a particular invocation, but also a list of defines to respect during expansion. Any preprocessor symbol not in the second list is completely left alone. An example is in order:

```
cpptreadlight -DY=22 --only=Y
```

would produce:

```
#include <foo>
#define baz
#define bar(a) do{(a)+1} \
               while(0)
#ifdef X
    #if Z > 5
      so_far_so_good = true;
    #endif
    #ifdef baz
    something();
    #endif
#else
  #if Z > 10
    wow().this.is.bad;
  #endif
#endif
```

and:

```
cpptreadlight -DY=22 -DZ=8 -DX --only=Y,baz,Z
```

would give me:

```
#include <foo>
#define bar(a) do{(a)+1} \
               while(0)
#ifdef X
      so_far_so_good = true;
    something();
#else
#endif
```

Notice that even though `X` is defined, it was left behind, because it didn't appear in the `--only` list. Also note that `baz` *was* in the `--only` list, and so was expanded once it was defined in the source.

---

I tried a hack-solution: escaping uninteresting stuff using a pipeline like the following (my own gsub tool is used, but it does what you might expect):

```
function escape_tr() { 
   gsub "#(define|include)" '@@@\1' < $1 | 
     (echo '#include "simple.h"' && gsub '\\$' "%%%") | 
       cpp -C -P -DY=301 -DZ > $1.new 
}
```

Now I can filter out a lot of stuff, and then put the things I want the preprocessor to expand in `simple.h`. Comments are left alone, and `#line` directives are left out.

This *almost* does the trick, in that includes are not pulled in, `#define` blocks are not defined, and so not expanded into the body. But of course it doesn't let me specify the set of conditional logic that I'd like to keep in the output. That's bad. Some of it is important to keep conditional.

`#if` nests, and the `#else` and `#endif` tokens don't lexically match, putting the problem beyond a regex pipeline. I need a full-blown parser, something practically identical to cpp itself, but with finer grained control of what is expanded.

Hence, before digging into a preprocessor to implement this, I thought I'd ask if anyone has solved this problem before. I can't be the only one to have inherited a preprocessor spaghetti nest full of dead branches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a tool called "[unifdef](http://freshmeat.net/projects/unifdef/)" that will do what you want.

Comment: Confirmed that this in combination with my `escape_tr` shell script in the original question can perform all of the actions I'd like done on this source-base. Thanks Paul. 

Something like `cpptreadlight` should exist though. It generalizes both `unifdef` and `cpp`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need `escape_tr`, but possibly I'm missing something.

Comment: `unifdef` only deals with ifdefs. I also want to elide some of the redundant defines. Granted this wasn't part of what I was asking in the original question.

Comment: I don't think that's true - if you do "unifdef -DY=22" it will take care of all the "#if Y..." as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at [boost.wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/wave/index.html)

from the boost.wave preface:

*So the main goals for the Wave project are:*

- full conformance with the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) [1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/wave/index.html) and with the C99 standard (INCITS/ISO/IEC 9899:1999)
- usage of Spirit[4] for the parsing parts of the game (certainly :-)
- maximal usage of STL and/or Boost libraries (for compactness and maintainability)
- straightforward extendability for the implementation of additional features
  building a flexible library for different C++ lexing and preprocessing needs