# Preprocess C files, but only expand #ifdefs?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'd like to generate a minimal source code of the Linux kernel that would pass `make allnoconfig`. I managed to build a sample that only contains files used in the compilation process, but would now like to shrink that list. I know I can specify a custom preprocessor in the build process. The question is: how to preprocess C files so that all of the code would be copied verbatim, expect for #ifdefs which would be parsed and expanded  - or skipped if the condition is not met?

Comment: You can run the preprocessor by itself, but that will also expand macros. I don't think there's a way to make it only process `#ifdef`

Comment: Perhaps useful: [coan/unifdef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45231857/1566221)

Comment: You can try the `unifdef` program.